# message.author.id returning bot id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a modmail system and whenever it creates a ticket, it logs your id in quick.db (for sending messages from the dm to the support ticket), Although, whenever I try to do that, it returns the ID for the bot.

Here is the code I use

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if(db.has(`ticket-${message.author.id}`)){
    console.log(message.author.id)
    if(message.channel.type == "dm"){
      const channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === `ticket-${message.author.id}` && c.type === 'text');
      channel.send(message.content)
    }
  }
})
```

Whenever I open a ticket and send something it sends the bots id in the console, not my own.
I am using version 12 for this project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`channel.send(message.content)` emits the `message` event just like any other user message. To ignore bot messages add

```js
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

To the top of your message listener.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
   if (message.author.bot) return;
   // Your Code ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It really helped!